# Precedence in Eigen transformations and difference between pretranslate and translate

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am a bit confused with the order used by Eigen when combining transformations.

What is the difference between `translate()` and `pretranslate()`?

Because in practice I get different results when I do this:

```
  Eigen::Affine3d t_res = Eigen::Affine3d::Identity();
  t_res.pretranslate(t1)
      .translate(t2)
      .rotate(t3);
```

...and this:

```
  Eigen::Affine3d t_res = Eigen::Affine3d::Identity();
  t_res.translate(t1)
      .translate(t2)
      .rotate(t3);
```

Also, for the last code snippet, does Eigen do this

```
t_res = (t1 * ( t2 * t3 ))
```

or this

```
t_res = ((t1 *  t2) * t3 )
```

?

Comment: The order in which C++ executes operands is sometimes arcane or not defined at all, but in this case it's left to right. The output of each function is the object on which the next function is being executed. Since the output of each function is a reference to `*this`, the object is modifying itself in a left to right chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pretranslate` and `translate` differ in whether they apply the argument from the right or from the left

```
A.pretranslate(B)
```

applies `B` on the from the left, returning `B*A`, while

```
A.translate(B)
```

applies it from the right, returning `A*B`.

Regarding the order, `A.translate(B)` returns a reference to the resulting matrix, so it will iteratively call `translate`/`rotate` on the results of the previous operation, doing

```
t_res = (((t_res* t1) *  t2) * t3 )
```

But as matrix multiplication is associative, the order of the operations only matters when it comes to numerical errors due to the floating point representation.

The order of the matrices however does affect the result (as the multiplication is not commutative), which is why `pretranslate` and `translate` give different results.

---

Edit: As [ggael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641621/ggael) pointed out, for `t_res` being the identity, both versions should give the same result

Comment: Thanks, I now understand that in my OP's first code snippet what's happening behind the scenes is `t_res = (((t1 * Identity()) * t2) * t3 )`, as opposed to the second snippet in the OP in which `t_res = (((Identity() * t1) * t2) * t3 )` is performed.

Comment: Exactly, but since you start from the identity you should get the same result for this particular case, which is what I observe.

Comment: If the matrices are really large, numerical errors from floating point operations can screw that up, but you are right, in this case, I would expect both to yield the same.

Answer (score 3):

Kai already answered your question, but I'd like to strongly recommend avoiding those functions and write explicit code:

```
Vector3d t1, t2;
Matrix3d mat_rot;
Affine3d t_res = Translation3f(t2) * mat_rot * Translation3f(t1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! In your example, what is the precedence for computing `t_res`?

Comment: By default it follows c++ rules, so `a*b*c` <=> `(a*b)*c` if that's what you asked.